# NodeJS error "cannot use import statement outside a module"

Tags: javascript, import, module, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to import tensorflowjs in a javascript file, but i get the error:

```
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:983:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1033:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1103:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:914:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:822:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1143:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:16:11
```

Having read other answers on SO, I specified type = "module" in my index.html file but it is still not working.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to use server-side/node code on the client side/in the browser. Use this instead: https://www.tensorflow.org/js/tutorials/setup#browser_setup

Comment: Thank you, it works for tensorflowjs, but now I need to import models from a Github repository that is installed with npm. I get the same error, and I can't find the equivalent of script tags...

Comment: So is the Github project still client-side? Not every module has a client-side equivalent obviously, since some things can only be done on the server-side.

Comment: Here's the Github I need : https://github.com/zqingr/tfjs-yolov3/blob/master/README_EN.md

I have the same import error when writing "import { yolov3, yolov3Tiny } from 'tfjs-yolov3' " in the main.js file.

Comment: Again: you cannot just import a random module and expect it to work. Most modules are written for a node/webpack environment. That github project is a node project. There is nothing you can put in script tags because it simply wasn't written that way.

Comment: Okay I understand, but does that mean there's no way of importing this module in my project ?

Answer (score 0):

To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json

```
import * as tf from "@tensorflow/tfjs";
```

or
try to prove this

```
   // import * as tf from "@tensorflow/tfjs";
    const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs');
```

Answer (score 0):

As told in the comments, you are using a node import in a browser project. An easy workaround would be using a minified (or non minified) jS bundle with the tfjs library.
Thus, in the HTML file, you'd do

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
```

And directly use tensorflowjs as tf (you *do not* need the import statement)